# Add attribute to a date picker using Swift 3

Tags: swift, date

I need my date picker to display custom dates. How can I add them?

For example:

Feb 2 2017

Feb 5 2017

Feb 24 2017

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try and do this? Please don't just ask people to do the work for you. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work, to demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from giving obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have too many custom dates, then you can create an array with these dates, something like

```
var dates = ["Feb 2 2017", ...]
```

Then declare your custom picker view

```
var customDatePicker: UIPickerView!
```

Instantiate it in `viewDidLoad` and set delegate and dataSource

```
customDatePicker = UIPickerView()
customDatePicker.dataSource = self
customDatePicker.delegate = self
```

Then implement necessary dataSource and delegate functions.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return dates.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dates[row]
}
```